# How to install the "google/apiclient" package in a openclient 3 project with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, opencart, opencart-3

I don't have much experience with php, as i usually work with .net c# and windows environments. 
However, I have now an opencart 3 installation on my local windows machine running on Apache2.
Opencart is working fine. I also have the same opencart on a live production server, also running fine.

I want to do an implementation of google signin on the site, and i would prefer to use the backend for this and not the javascript frontend provided by google.

To implement it I need the google-api-php-client library which I can download from here:
`https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client`, or use composer to install it.

I installed composer for windows on my local machine.

As far as i see, all the libraries are in 'system\storage\vendor' folder.

I opened a command window by clicking on the project folder (htdocs) and ran the command: `composer require google/apiclient:"^2.4.1"`.

After the installation, i can not see the library in the vendor folder, but i can see two new files: composer.json and composer.lock.

Also in the `system\storage\vendor\composer` folder, there is a file called `installed.json` and in it i can see all the old libraries there, but not the new one.

So, what am I missing?

In the docs for the library it says to include the 'system\storage\vendor\' autoload.php file in the new page, but opencart does that much before in the flow on startup.

So, in the new page i called `$gClient = new Google_Client();`, but ofcourse it is not recognized.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where do you run `composer require`? In the folder `system\storage`?

Answer (score 0):

The `composer.json` file for opencart is located in the **top-level** root directory of the project (one level above `upload/` holding the `.htaccess`) file.

The dependencies are stored under `upload/system/storage/vendor/` (See the project's [composer.json](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/3.0.3.4/composer.json#L9)).

You need to invoke the command:

```
composer require google/apiclient:"^2.4.1"
```

inside the top-level directory to install the `google/apiclient` package.